# Template doesn't receive full context dictionary

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to pass a context dictionary to my template but troubles arise.

If i pass the following context, it works and i can loop through it:

```
subjects_list = Subject.objects.all()
context = {'subjects': subjects_list}
return render(request, 'main_page/subjects.html', context)
```

And i loop it with the following code:

```
{% if subjects %}
    <ul>
        {% for subject in subjects %}
        <li>{{ subject.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>       
    {% else %}
        <p> No subjects available </p>
{% endif %}
```

When i try to add 1 more key item to the context, i always get no value back.
e.g

```
subjects_list = Subject.objects.all()
context = {'subjects': subjects_list,
           'temp_list': [1, 2, 3]}
return render(request, 'main_page/subjects.html', context)
```

If i try to access the temp_list with:

```
{{ temp_list }}
```

The temp_list is always blank, whatever i add to it but the subjects still do work. (i used a list of numbers for the sake of the post.  What i firstly tried to add was a list of object from a different model i have.)

Comment: Where are you using temp_list, in relation to the rest of the template?

Comment: Wherever i use it, it doesn't display it.
After the {% if subjects %}, after </ul>, after {% endif %} same effect.  Nothing is displayed.

Comment: Well, it's not possible to replicate this with the information you've provided; obviously, it is possible to pass more than one element to a template. Does this happen with all your views, or just one?

Comment: Just checked on different view and it worked on that one.
Can't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Jesus christ, i can't believe it. 
I was making changes on different view than the one i was displaying on browser.
Seems i need to rest a bit, overthinking isn't good.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.
The context that i was manipulating was different than the page i was checking on the browser.
Everything works fine now.  Just needed some clean air.

Comment: I will do but i need 2 days!